# Android - ListItem RelativeLayout text in center of TextViews with height wrap_content

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-relativelayout, vertical-alignment

I have a `ListActivity` with a custom `ArrayAdapter` that uses a `list_item.xml`. In this xml file I have an `ImageView` and three `TextViews`.

The `ImageView` and first two `TextViews` are alligned left next to each other, and the third `TextView` is alligned at the right. This works all as intented.

Now I also want to allign the `TextViews` in the center of the `ListItem`.

Right now I use a `RelativeLayout` so I'm able to align the third `TextView` to the right, and I use `match_parent` on the `TextViews' layout_height`, since I've read somewhere it's required to align the text in a `TextView` to the center in `RelativeLayouts`.

Here is my current `list_item.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- The View for a single CheckListItem -->
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/item_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/checkbox_content_description"
        android:src="@drawable/checkbox_unchecked"
        android:background="@layout/transparent_background"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_amount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/image"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:textIsSelectable="false" />

    <!-- NOTE: layout_toLeftOf has @+id/ instead of @id to create the R.id here -->
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tv_product_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv_amount"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tv_price"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/image"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"

        android:background="@layout/border" />
        <!-- TODO: Remove test border -->

    <!-- NOTE: id has @id instead of @+id, because we created the ID in the tv_product_name in the layout_toLeftOf -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@id/tv_price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/image"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:textIsSelectable="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

With the following result:

[image]

What I want instead is:

[image]

---

EDIT 1:

After changing `android:gravity="center_vertical"` to `android:gravity="center"` in the three TextViews, the Text is only aligned in the center horizontally, but not vertically:

[image]

Comment: Change gravity=center

Comment: @Sania If I change the `gravity="center_vertical"` to `"center"` in the TextViews, the text is only aligned to the center horizontally, but not vertically.. :S (see Edit 1)

Comment: Sorry change it to center horizontal

Comment: @KevinCruijssen try android:lineSpacingExtra for TextView

Comment: @Sania both `center` and `center_horizontal` give the same result (picture in edit 1), and `center_vertical` doesn't work for some reason..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Try this way,i hope this will help you to solve your problem...

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/item_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/checkbox_content_description"
        android:src="@drawable/checkbox_unchecked"
        android:background="@layout/transparent_background"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_amount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:textIsSelectable="false" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_product_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:background="@layout/border" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/tv_price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:textIsSelectable="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, after changing the `LinearLayout's gravity` to `center_vertical` instead of `center` it works exactly as I want it. Accepted as answer.

Answer (score 0):

i jsut edited your one xml.try with this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/item_layout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
  <TextView  android:id="@+id/floraCompStat"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image"
             android:background="@drawable/bg"
             android:gravity="center_vertical"
             android:text="TextView" />
```

bg.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle"
        >
        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
        <stroke android:width="1sp" android:color="#FF0000" />
        <padding android:left="15dp"/>
    </shape>
```